# Many numpy array manipulations in one array

Tags: python, numpy

I need to translate a matlab code to python numpy code

I have 4 2-dimension arrays (*A, B, C and D*) and want to create a new one *"res"*.

the code in matlab

```
index1 = find(A == 2 & B > C);
index2 = find(A == 2 & B >= D & B <= C);

res = uint8(zeros(100,100));
res(index1) = 5;
res(index2) = 4;
```

in Python/numpy I figured out I can create new arrays like this:

```
res = ((A == 2) & (B > C)) * 5
res = ((A == 2) & (B >= D) & (B <= C)) * 4
```

but how can I combine this 2 results in only one array? Like the matlab code does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The translation (in this case) is almost one-for-one:

```
index1 = ((A == 2) & (B > C)) 
index2 = ((A == 2) & (B >= D) & (B <= C)) 
res = np.zeros((100, 100), dtype='uint8')
res[index1] = 5
res[index2] = 4
```

Alternatively, you could define `res` as

```
res = np.where(A == 2, np.where(B > C, 5, np.where(B >= D, 4, 0)), 0)
```

though I don't think that helps readability :)

---

PS. As Mr. E suggests, `mask1` might be a better variable name than `index1` since `index` (usually) suggests integer values while `mask` suggest booleans, which is what we have here.

Comment: Can I be really pedantic and suggest not to use `index1` for a boolean mask/array?